# Application is lagging due to conversion of images into data for storing them in the database. (Launch screen only)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, image-processing

Can someone help me out, i am facing a issues since many days.

My Application is lagging(Users feel like the app is almost struck) at the launch screen while handling image data from server and saving it in the local SQLite Database. It would be great if someone could provide me with some solution for the same.

Thank You.

Comment: Why aren't you saving them as files?

Comment: store filepath in db and write data into document directory.

Comment: I am with @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani.

Comment: you mean to say we should just save the filepath to DB and always load images from the server? Yes, thats right but we need the application to work offline also.

Comment: @vardhanReddy are you downloading images in table or first download all images and then show it . please provide code what are you doing now.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to figure out the cause without any code but if the user is complaining that the application is lagging, there is a good chance that you are doing work on the main thread and locking up the UI.  You should do as much of this work as you can on a background thread as to not freeze the User Interface.  If your app is useless unless this data is ready, you should design a flow where the application lets the user know that it is doing some work instead of just freezing the application UI.

Comment: i have to display the images from the server immediately after the launch screen, and if i do the same in the background the app would be empty or still loading which would be considered as another error. And probably when i directly display the app images by getting the images from server asynchronously it is very much successful but when i am trying to do the same with DB, that is Server to DB and display images from DB, that is where i am facing the issue. Do you think is their any solution for the same.

Comment: And more over when i am trying to do the same in the background thread instead of main thread, i am getting the image data as empty.

Comment: dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul); dispatch_async(queue, ^{ //This is what you will load lazily
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagurl]]; dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    generalimg = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    
                });
            });